# Recreate dynamically created buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-controls

I know about ASP.NET page life cycle but I'm confused. I have code here which creates buttons from database records. After I click on them, they dissapear with no code triggered. :( I know I have to recreate them in Page_Init but I don't know how. Please help! This is my code:

```
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            SqlCommand myCom = new SqlCommand("select ID,client from tposClient where CardNo='" + cNo + "'", con);

            myReader = myCom.ExecuteReader();

            Panel panel1 = new Panel();
            panel1.Style["text-align"] = "Center";
            panel1.Style["background"] = "blue";
            div_login.Visible = false;

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string b = myReader["client"].ToString();
                string id = myReader["ID"].ToString();

                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Text = b;
                btn.ID = id;
                btn.Style["width"] = "100px";
                btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
                panel1.Controls.Add(btn);

                panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
                form1.Style.Add("display", "block");
                form1.Controls.Add(panel1);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception k)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(k.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            cmdselect.Dispose();
            if (con != null)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You know that you can even use `UserControls` in a web-databound control like GridView or Repeater? Dynamical controls are unnecessary  in most cases.

Comment: I'm not sure. You mean that I should read data in grid and make "buttons". What is your solution?

Comment: I would embed these controls in a reusable [`UserControl`](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/user-controls/using/). Then you can add them to a `TemplateField` of a `GridView` or in a [`Repeater`-control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8f2zez5.aspx). To get your dynamic code above working, you need to recreate the controls on postbacks with the same id as before.

Comment: Side note: Use `Parameterized` queries. You're leaving yourself open to [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: That's the point, recreating after postback. I'm confused, don't know how :(

Comment: You should at least add the panel declaratively to the page. Where is above code located? Do you get an exception, have you used the debugger? I hope that the connection is not static.

Comment: All code is in one file. I'm getting buttons but after I click one of them they dissapear and no code executed. (code is for showing message box as sample, btw. that code is working if I create button on `Page_Load`)

Answer (score 1):

You should just put the `Button` inside a `ListView` control which will repeat for each result you get back. It will be much easier to work with the buttons this way, and you don't have to deal with recreating the controls on each `Postback`.

Create a ListView with a button inside of it

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="lv1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="my Text />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

After you do your data access, create a `Dictionary<string, string>` to hold the text and id of each button, and you can then use that to bind your `ListView`.

```
//Your data access code
Dictionary<string, string> buttonIdsWithText = new Dictionary<string, string>();
while(myReader.Read())
{
    string buttonText = myReader["client"].ToString();
    string buttonId = myReader["ID"].ToString();
    buttonIdsWithText.Add(buttonId, buttonText);
}
lv1.DataSource = buttonIdsWithText;
lv1.DataBind();
```

Create an `ItemDataBound` event handler so you can set your button text

```
public void lv1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType != ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        return;
    }

    KeyValuePair<string, string> idWithText = 
        (KeyValuePair<string, string>)e.Item.DataItem;
    Button myButton = e.Item.FindControl("btn1") as Button;
    myButton.Text = idWithText.Value;
}
```

If you need to set the button id specifically to the id you get from the database (and you're using .NET 4) you can set the button's `ClientIDMode` to `Static` and set the id to the id you want.

Comment: I have problem with last part. 

`...KeyValuePair<string, string> idWithText = (KeyValuePair<string, string>)e.Item.DataItem;...`

Comment: What is the issue? I can't help if I don't know what's wrong. You should be able to cast your `DataItem` as a `KeyValuePair`